# Calling Ajax in an iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ajax

I'm creating an iOS native app version of a web app that uses jQuery to fetch information from its database. Is there a way to make an ajax call in iOS that returns a JSON object?

Comment: What have you looked at? There are tons of tutorials out there on how to get JSON from a web service on iOS :) It won't be an `ajax` call per se, but you will get what you want.

Comment: No, you can't make an ajax call but you can use iOS native classes such as NSURLSession. (Actually that's not strictly true, you could call ajax if you ran javascript within the app.)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I ended up just performing the get call through NSURLSession and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to take a look at `NSURLSessionDataTask`. This will return JSON as an `NSData` object . Here is a link to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataTask_class/).

If you want to make the request asyncronously, `NSURLConnection` class [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/).